# PHP cantidad de horas solo si estan entre un rango

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, diff

Inecesito calcular las horas que un trabajador realiza y cuantas de esas son en horario nocturno.
el horario nocturno es de 22:00 a 06:00
ejemplo: si un trabajador entra a las 20:00hs y sale a las 24:00hs trabajo 4 horas pero solo 2 horas fueron nocturnas.

debido a que el horario nocturno puede ir de un dia al otro tambien tengo que tener en cuenta la fecha.

este es mi codigo para obtener la cantidad total de horas:

```
$fecha = '5/12/2020';
$fechaOut = $fecha;

$checkIn = '20:00';
$checkOut = '24:00';

if ($checkIn >= $checkOut) {
    $fechaOut = date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fecha).' +1 day'));
}

$ts1 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fecha.' '.$checkIn));
$ts2 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fechaOut.' '.$checkOut));

$diff = ($ts2 - $ts1) / 3600;

echo $diff;
echo 'hs.<br>';
```

pero no se como puedo hacer para obtener solo las horas nocturnas.

Answer (score 2):

Si usas marcas de tiempo por todo el camino lo puedes manejar con un ciclo `for`, tal y como cualquier índice, sólo que se incrementa en 3600 segundos (una hora).

```
$checkIn  = strtotime('2020-12-05 20:00');
$checkOut = strtotime('2020-12-05 24:00');

$horasTot = 0;
$horasNoc = 0;
for( $t = $checkIn; $t < $checkOut; $t += 3600 ){
    $horasTot++;
    if( date('H',$t) >= 22 || date('H',$t) < 6 )
        $horasNoc++;
}
echo "$horasNoc/$horasTot";
```

Resultado: `2/4`

Para incluir los minutos es la misma idea pero incrementando por 60 segundos, y con ayuda de `mktime()` y `date()` le damos formato:

```
$checkIn  = strtotime('2020-12-05 20:10');
$checkOut = strtotime('2020-12-05 24:45');

$minTot = 0;
$minNoc = 0;
for( $t = $checkIn; $t < $checkOut; $t += 60 ){
    $minTot++;
    if( date('H',$t) >= 22 || date('H',$t) < 6 )
        $minNoc++;
}
echo 'Totales / Nocturnas: '.date('H:i',mktime(0,$minTot,0,0,0,0))
   . ' / '
   . date('H:i',mktime(0,$minNoc,0,0,0,0))
   ;
```

Resultado: `Totales / Nocturnas: 4:35 / 02:45`

Comment: esta muy interesante tu código y se ve muy simple, como puedo agregar los minutos de diferencia??

Comment: Ayudaría un ejemplo con los minutos.