# calcular las horas solo si están entre dos horas PHP

Tags: php

Necesito calcular las horas que están comprendidas entre dos horas:

por ejemplo tengo un horario de **18:00 a 02:00;**
necesito saber cuantas de esas horas están dentro **22:00 a 06:00**.

para este caso seria **4hs**;

como puedo hacer eso en PHP?

*aclaro que también necesito saber los minutos

Comment: Que has intentado al momento?

Comment: ¿Dispones también de la fecha o únicamente de las horas?

Comment: las fechas no son necesarias, puedo usar cualquier fecha si fuera necesario siempre va a ser el mismo dia o un dia mas al finalizar

Comment: hasta el momento no tengo ni idea de como hacer esto, ya calcule otros datos que necesito pero en este no se como empezar @BetaM

Comment: Esta pregunta está mal formulada. Sugiero que se haga una edición o se elimine.

Comment: Por si acaso te vale, en este ejemplo hacen pasos similares: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379949/php-cantidad-de-horas-solo-si-estan-entre-un-rango?rq=1

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo algo así:

```
<?php

$hs=[
 '18:00',  // $hs[0]
 '02:00',  // $hs[1]
 '22:00',  // $hs[2]
 '06:00',  // $hs[3]
];

// convierto las horas a formato numérico
foreach($hs as $i=>$h)
    $hs[$i]=strtotime('2001-01-01 '.$h);

// si la segunda hora es inferior a la primera
// entiendo que será del día siguiente
if($hs[1]<$hs[0])
    $hs[1]+=24*60*60;
if($hs[3]<$hs[2])
    $hs[3]+=24*60*60;

// paso las horas comunes a los primeros elementos
if($hs[0]<$hs[2])
    $hs[0]=$hs[2];
if($hs[1]>$hs[3])
    $hs[1]=$hs[3];

// calculo la diferencia en segundos entre ambas horas
$d = $hs[1]-$hs[0];
if($d<0) $d=0;

// muestro esa diferencia en formato horas:minutos
$h = floor($d/3600);
$m = floor(($d - $h*3600)/60);

echo sprintf('%02d',$h).':'.sprintf('%02d',$m);
```

Answer (score 0):

por si alguien le sirve, este código funciona bien.

```
if ($he >= $inicio_noche && $hs <= $fin_noche) {
            echo '<b>trabajo en horario nocturno</b><br>';
            $diff = $he->diff($hs);
            $horas['nocturnas'] = new datetime('2020-01-01 '.$diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
        } elseif ($he >= $fin_noche && $hs <= $inicio_noche) {
            echo '<b>trabajo en horario diurno</b><br>';
            $horas['nocturnas'] = new datetime('2020-01-01 00:00:00');
        } elseif ($he < $inicio_noche && $hs <= $fin_noche) {
            echo '<b>entro en horario diurno, salio en nocturno</b><br>';
            $diff = $inicio_noche->diff($hs);
            $horas['nocturnas'] = new datetime('2020-01-01 '.$diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
        } elseif ($he < $inicio_noche && $hs >= $inicio_noche) {
            echo '<b>entro en horario diurno, salio en nocturno</b><br>';
            $diff = $inicio_noche->diff($hs);
            $horas['nocturnas'] = new datetime('2020-01-01 '.$diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
        } elseif ($he >= $inicio_noche && $hs > $fin_noche) {
            echo '<b>entro en horario nocturno, salio en diurno</b><br>';
            $diff = $he->diff($fin_noche);
            $horas['nocturnas'] = new datetime('2020-01-01 '.$diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
        } elseif ($he < $fin_noche && $hs > $fin_noche) {
            echo '<b>entro horario nocturno, salio en diurno</b><br>';
            $diff = $he->diff($fin_noche);
            $horas['nocturnas'] = new datetime('2020-01-01 '.$diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
        }
```

- $he = hora de entrada
- $hs hora de salida
- $inicio_noche = hora de inicio horario noche
- $fin_noche = hora de inicio horario noche

todas las variables están en formato **DateTime**