# ¿Cómo puedo quitar horas no laborales a una resta de dos fechas en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una resta entre dos fechas, se que se puede hacer así

$total= $inicio->diff($fin);
El horario laboral es de lunes a viernes de 9:00 a 19:00, suponiendo que quiero restar dos fechas pero hay una diferencia de más de un día, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para quitar las horas no laborales?

Comment: Revisa [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379949/).

Comment: Me parece que esto es mucho más complejo que un simple cálculo entre dos fechas. ¿Qué hay de los días no laborables, como podría ser sábados/domingos y festivos? [Revisa esta respuesta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195476/186960), ese código te dará una idea para construir una función robusta que te calcula las horas laborables entre cualquier rango de fechas.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!